# Monolog implementation with common class

Tags: php, oop, logging, monolog

I succeeded in implementing a Monolog logger for test purposes. And now I'm trying to use it in a project. This project doesn't use any MVC framework.

I'm trying to write a common class file to wrap access to the Monolog instance.

Common class file: File: app_log.php

```
require 'autoload.php';
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\RotatingFileHandler;
use Monolog\Processor\UidProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\WebProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\MemoryUsageProcessor;
use Monolog\Processor\ProcessIdProcessor;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;

class app_log {
  public function info(){
    $logger = new Logger('applog');
    $handler = new RotatingFileHandler('useractivity.log', 0, Logger::INFO);
    $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter("[%datetime%] %extra.process_id% %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %extra% %context% \n"));
    $logger->pushHandler($handler);
    $logger->pushProcessor(new WebProcessor);
  }  
}
```

Other File: users.php

```
include_once 'app_log.php';
class users extends dbconnector{
    function login(){
      // Some project code. 
      $logger = new app_log();
      $logger->info('User logged successfully');
    }
}
```

Up to this works well and i want to include filename, method name,  request parameters. But i am getting `app_log.php` file name instead `users.php` and Method name is `'info'` instead `'login'` in the logs.

Example:

```
[2018-06-07 20:55:50] 4410 applog.INFO: User logged successfully {"file":"/var/www/portal/lib/app_log.php","line":59,"class":"app_log","function":"info"} []
```

Could you guys help on this part?

Comment: Why don't you use the `singleton` pattern in your `app_log` class it will make your logging lot more easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid your whole design is simply wrong.

Instead of instantiating a new `Logger` every time you need to log, you should be creating a single `$logger` to use as a service around your application.

Without knowing more about your application (and having to rewrite your application would make the question *too broad* anyway), it's hard to guess how to implement **dependency injection** here.

But a simplistic and naive approach would be:

```
class users extends dbconnector {

    protected $logger;

    public function _construct(Logger $logger) {
       $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    function login() {
      $this->logger->info('User logged successfully');
    }
}
```

And then:

```
$logger  = new Logger('applog');
$handler = new RotatingFileHandler('useractivity.log', 0, Logger::INFO);
$handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter("[%datetime%] %extra.process_id% %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %extra% %context% \n"));
$logger->pushHandler($handler);
$logger->pushProcessor(new WebProcessor);
$logger->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor);

$users = new users($logger);
```

If you inject that `Logger` instance in the objects that need it, you can use it directly without having to create your own "wrapper" (which in your example was poorly designed), and the output in the log files will match your expectations.

Notice that you are not using the [`IntrospectionProcessor`](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog/blob/master/doc/02-handlers-formatters-processors.md#processors), which you'd need to capture the filename and file line number. In the above example I'm also pushing it in `$logger`, the `Logger` instance.

(And also note that simply adding this processor to your code won't solve your issue, since the call to `Logger::info()` would always happen in `app_log::info()`).

Remember that you'll need to add the corresponding `use` statement: `use Monolog\Processor\IntrospectionProcessor;`

I do not know all the details of your system, and can't build it all for you anyway, but if dependency injection is still too much for you, you could just cheat temporarily with a global-state approach.

E.g.:

```
function get_logger() {
   static $logger;

   if ($logger !== null) {
      return $logger;
   }

   $logger  = new Logger('applog');
   $handler = new RotatingFileHandler('useractivity.log', 0, Logger::INFO);
   $handler->setFormatter(new LineFormatter("[%datetime%] %extra.process_id% %channel%.%level_name%: %message% %extra% %context% \n"));
   $logger->pushHandler($handler);
   $logger->pushProcessor(new WebProcessor);
   $logger->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor);

   return $logger;
}
```

You could put this in a file that you `require_once`, and in each of these places where you need access to the logger you can simply do:

```
 get_logger()->info('write to the log!');
```

**This is not something I'd endorse**, but a crummy workaround for you to get moving until you advance somewhat in your understanding of other OOP topics. This is nothing else than a poor's man [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), which more often than not is a pattern to avoid anyway; but that could help you right now..

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how to make the second part reusable because i have many Class file like 'users'? And i cannot use the $logger in every file. Could you please suggest me on this?

Comment: Exactly the same as in this case. Your other classes "depend" on the Logger service, so you should "inject" the service in each of this classes. An usual way to do it is to inject the object on instantiation: change your constructors to receive the additional $logger parameter and to set a private logger property. And then on each of these classes you can simply call `$this->logger->info()`.

Comment: Perfect! I got it now. Thanks for your great help.

Answer (score -1):

`WebProcessor` will not add data you need, I mean file and line.

`IntrospectionProcessor` does what you need, try

```
$logger->pushProcessor(new IntrospectionProcessor());
```

Comment: This is wrong. Since in the OPs code the call originates in `app_log::info()`, they'll get exactly the same result.

Comment: @yivi your approach will also won't give needed results. But if author combines two approaches he will get what he wants

Comment: Since the OP already printed a log file with this information, I assumed they had **that** part figured out. But you are right, they are missing this this processor in the $logger instance.